# Validation for Dynamically Created Radio button control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am creating radiobutton lists dynamically for my questionnaire. I will have 5 list items in each radio button list. I need to validate the radiobuttons which are created in the runtime (Dynamically). I need to validate on server side.Any idea how can i do that. The radiobutton lists are generated dynamically using a Server control with first List Id as `Q_1` second as `Q_2` so on. Options for first List as `Q_1_0`, `Q_1_1`, `_Q_1_2` so on. I am try like this

```
RadioButtonList objRadioConfirm = new RadioButtonList();
objRadioConfirm.Items.Add(new ListItem("1"));
objRadioConfirm.Items.Add(new ListItem("2"));

RequiredFieldValidator objRequiredFieldConfirm = new RequiredFieldValidator();
objRequiredFieldConfirm.ControlToValidate = objRadioConfirm.ClientID;
objRequiredFieldConfirm.ErrorMessage = "Please select all;
```

Comment: Please, post what have you tried!

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I posted the try am following

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Web Forms. If not, then you can set them a name or an ID and then use it as:

```
Validation.RequireField("nameoffield", "You need to write something here");
```

But I don't know why you are doing so.
The radio buttons are selected at max of ONE! Second cannot be selected untill or unless its name is different. SO why not do something like: 
if the name has an empty value, no radio selected. Send him back to page and ask him to reselect the radio button!

Use the List Id or use that as the name of the Radio button. Thats more helpfull!